# Getting Unhandled Rejection (TypeError)

Tags: reactjs, api, jwt, local-storage, axios

I am making a Web Application with ReactJS using JWT token and Axios library for API calls. On my local machine everything works fine. But on other computer connected to same Wi-Fi gives me an error. Please, give me a hint, or some article how to handle correct the API calls with Axios.

```
onSubmit =(event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        if(formValid(this.state)){
            var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user-data'));
            if(data!= null){
                localStorage.removeItem('user-data');
            }
            axios.post('https://localhost:44397/api/auth/login', {
                email: this.state.email,
                password: this.state.password
            }).then((result) => {
                if(result.status === 200){
                    localStorage.setItem('user-data', JSON.stringify(result.data))
                    this.props.history.push("/dashboard");
                };
            }).catch(err => {
                console.error(err);
                if(err){
                    const {data} = err.response;
                for(let key of Object.keys(data)){
                    switch(key){
                        case "email":
                            console.log(data.email);
                            let formErrors = {...this.state.formErrors};
                            formErrors.email = data.email;
                            this.setState({formErrors});
                        break;
                        case "password":
                            let formErrors2 =  {...this.state.formErrors};
                            console.log(data.password);
                            formErrors2.password = data.password;
                            this.setState({formErrors: formErrors2});
                        break;    
                        default:
                        break;
                    } 
                }

                };

            });
        };
    };
```

Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): undefined is not an object(evaluating 'err.response.data')

Answer (score 0):

you are using localhost in axios post request, you need to change this to some live api url or IP of your PC like

```
https://192.168.3.10:44397/api/auth/login
```